# How do you open a file for shared writing in C?

Tags: c, windows

I only found how to do it in C++ which is somthing like CreateFile(.... FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ....) but found nothing on how to do it in C.

Comment: What leads you to believe `CreateFile` is C++?

Comment: Note that multiple writers in append mode is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible in plain ISO C, which only offers the function [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

However, on Microsoft Windows, you can call the platform-specific function [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea), which offers this feature as an extension. You can use this function also when using the C programming language. It is not restricted to C++. The Microsoft documentation of the Windows API does not distinguish between C and C++, so when it refers to C++, it also means C.